# Can any one please tell me how many objects are created in background when we create an custom object

Tags: custom-object

I was asked in an interview about how many objects are created in the background when you create a custom object. What is the answer to this?

Comment: Please only post questions where you have an idea of the solution and ask for help with what you have - see [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will create following objects along with main object depending on features which you have set in the organization (refer this picture, where I have created a dummy object called 'abc'):

You can use [Etherios EasyDescribe - Free MetaData Viewer/Extractor from AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ)

to find out the objects and associated relationships.
[image]

Comment: Sir May i Know where we can see these objects are created.

Comment: Mark this answer if it solves your purpose.

Comment: For the record, history isn't in that list, and most of those aren't "new" objects.